# How to render just part of the Sprite

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I want to make some simple tutorial in my game by showing pop-up animation. My problem occur when moving sprites get out of the tutorialView but keep being rendered. I need to show just those parts that are on the animation view.

[I need to hide the white "path" which goes out of the tutorial view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71wId.png)
[This is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFBSj.png)

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: becareful with terms like 'view'  save those for the UIView elements when working in swift.  Other than that, look into SKCropNode, this will help you filter out unneeded graphics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually very easy just took screenshot of the screen and cropped the middle so that I could put it in front of the tutorial and everything that went out of it was hidden underneath.